# Find the order of $\phi_{(1\,2\,4\,3)}$ in $\text{Inn}(S_5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

> We define $\phi_{(1\,2\,4\,3)}$ as $\phi_{(1\,2\,4\,3)}= (1\,2\,4\,3)x(3\,4\,2\,1)$ where $x\in \text{Inn}(S_5)$ and $\text{Inn}(S_5)=\{\phi_s: s\in S_5\}$. We are interested in finding when $(\phi_{(1\,2\,4\,3)})^n=e$.

In other words when $$(1\,2\,4\,3)x(3\,4\,2\,1)(1\,2\,4\,3)x(3\,4\,2\,1)\cdots (1\,2\,4\,3)x(3\,4\,2\,1)=e.$$ This simplifies to $x^n=e$. I'm not quite sure what to do from this point on. Clearly the identity element of $\text{Inn}(S_5)$ is just $exe=x$. But this doesn't make sense as that would imply that $e^n=e$ and there is no where to go from this.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the definition of $\phi_s$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde $\phi_s = sxs^{-1}$

Comment: Ah, good. Then you don't have to define $\phi_s=\phi_{(1243)}$ again as a special case. What exactly do you mean by $x^n=e$? Which $n$ did you get? Fo example, $n=1$ doesn't make sense, right? What about $n=2$?

Comment: Well, $\phi_s$ is an element of ${\rm Inn}(S_5)$, whose group operation is function composition, so wouldn't $\phi_s^n=\phi_s\circ\cdots\circ\phi_s$ be the function defined by $\phi_s^n(x)=s^nxs^{-n}$? This is not the same as what you seem to be talking about, namely $\phi_s(x)^n=(sxs^{-1})^n=sx^ns^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have a surjective homomorphism $\Phi: S_n \to Inn(S_n)$, $\Phi(\sigma)=\phi_{\sigma}$. As pointed out in the comments,
$$\phi_{\sigma}^n=\Phi(\sigma)^n = \Phi(\sigma^n)=\phi_{\sigma^n}.$$

Now, a general property of homomorphism implies that $|\phi_\sigma|$ divides $|\sigma|$ (in your example, $|(1243)|=4$). But in this case, we also know $\ker\Phi=Z(S_n)$. What does that tell you about $\Phi$ and $|\phi_\sigma|$?